# Powershell acces denied bulk users AD

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

Two weeks ago I've made a script for making bulk users on my AD.
I have a .ps1 file and a .csv file on my servers desktop.

Normally I can right-click on the .ps1 file and choose "Run with Powershell", and everything works fine.

This time I've got this. I really don't know what the problem could be:

[image]

My .ps1 file looks like:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Csv "C:\Users\laurent\Desktop\NewUsers.csv" | ForEach-Object {
 $userPrincinpal = $_."samAccountName" + "@cvoww.lokaal"
 $weergavenaam = $_."Firstname" + " " + $_."Lastname"
New-ADUser -Name $weergavenaam `
 -Path $_."ParentOU" `
 -SamAccountName  $_."samAccountName" `
 -UserPrincipalName  $userPrincinpal `
 -GivenName  $_."Firstname" `
 -SurName  $_."Lastname" `
 -DisplayName  $weergavenaam `
 -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $_."password" -AsPlainText -Force) `
 -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true  `
 -Description $_."description" `
 -Enabled $true;
}
Pause
```

My csv file looks like:

```
Firstname,Lastname,samAccountName,description,ParentOU,password
Julles,Coutelle,Julles.Coutelle,"Valerie M, Diverse cursussen","OU=Cursisten1718,DC=cvoww,DC=lokaal",cursist
Walter,Croquey,Walter.Croquey,"Valerie M, Diverse cursussen","OU=Cursisten1718,DC=cvoww,DC=lokaal",cursist
```

What could be the problem?
Thanks for helping me!
Laurent

Comment: DId your permissions change?

Comment: Have you tried running it as Admin?

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you on?

Comment: Right-click -> Run as Administrator

Comment: Just a thought. Any chance your RID master is not working? Can you add a user manually?

Comment: Hi!
Thank you all for the kind replies! I tried to do it as administrator, but at first there was not button to run the .ps1 file as admin. It's strange, because in the past, it did work without it.
Now I've found this: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/64349-run-administrator-add-ps1-file-context-menu-windows-10-a.html
Something that added the button to run it as admin.

Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Just a modification to make sure it runs as you expect:

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
#Requires -Version 3

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Import-Csv 'C:\Users\laurent\Desktop\NewUsers.csv' |
  ForEach-Object {
    $weergavenaam = "$($_.Firstname) $($_.Lastname)"

    $Params = @{
      Name = $weergavenaam
      Path = $_.ParentOU
      UserPrincipalName = "$($_.samAccountName)@cvoww.lokaal"
      SamAccountName = $_.samAccountName
      GivenName = $_.Firstname
      SurName = $_.Lastname
      DisplayName = $weergavenaam
      AccountPassword = (ConvertTo-SecureString $_.password -AsPlainText -Force)
      ChangePasswordAtLogon = $True
      Description = $_.description
      Enabled = $True
    }
    New-ADUser @Params
  }

PAUSE
```

Comment: Hi!
Thank you for your answer. However it did not solve the problem. The problem was that I could not run it as admin. Strange, because that wasn't a problem in the past.
I don't know a lot of powershell. What is the difference in your solution? Thanks!

Comment: @LaurentVeys using splatting, it reduces the chance for error when writing scripts as your parameters are defined in a hash table and easily changed and defined.  Additionally, it uses a `#requires` statement so the script itself won't run unless you run it as administrator (as intended) and will give you an error message stating as much.